# What does "Benefit of a second's distance" mean

Tags: british-english, sentence-meaning

I was watching *Silicon Valley* (HBO) and one of the characters said this:

> ”I grant you with the benefit of even a second's distance, this isn't a good look."

Now I understand the last bit and the first six words, but not the rest. So could anyone tell me what "*Benefit of even a second's distance*" means?

Comment: Do you have a link to the video ?

Comment: Here it is: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=S8MAV9jhf04 (The scene starts at around 3:52)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it’s the distance a vehicle travels in one second, and here just means with even a little perspective one could notice the issue.

> The "Rule of Seconds"
>   How can we determine whether the truck behind us is following too close and what can we do about it? That's where the "rule of seconds" applies.
>   At highway speeds, say 60 miles per hour, a vehicle is traveling about 88 feet per second. Most commercial truck drivers are taught to allow one second’s worth of travel distance per ten feet of the length of their truck, plus one extra second for safety, between themselves and the vehicle in front of them.
>   - http://www.allenandallen.com/blog/the-rule-of-seconds.html